# Not finding Run services in Loadbalancer backend service for region europe-west6

Tags: google-cloud-platform

It seems that literally a day before go-live, the GCP loadbalancers stopped working for Cloud Run containers in europe-west6

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2za5D.png

I can see them when I try to create a backend service, but when I'm forced to select a region, it doesn't find my cloud run containers on all projects:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQcqQ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZwSv.png

Answer (score 0):

The web front end is causing that problem right now, but you should still be able to accomplish those mappings via the CLI until the front end fix rolls out.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? Are you saying this is a Google Cloud Console GUI problem?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that this is an issue with Google Cloud Console GUI only. It will take a week or two to roll out the fix. Meanwhile please use gcloud CLI (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud)